# Choosing a "canonical" representant of a class of measurable functions based on the essential range

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)>0$, and let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be (Borel- or Lebesgue) measurable. Denote the class of functions a.e equal to $f$ by $[f]$.

Is there a $g\in [f]$ with $\operatorname{im} g=\operatorname{essran} f$ on every measurable set, with $\operatorname{essran} f$ being the essential range of $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure and let $f$ be the identity function.  Supposing such a $g$ exists, let $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:g(x)=f(x)\}$, which by assumption has full measure.  Pick a point $a\in A$ and let $B=A\setminus\{a\}$.  Then $B$ still has full measure, so the essential range of $f$ on $B$ is $\mathbb{R}$.  However, $a\not\in g(B)$, since $a\not\in B$ and $g$ is the identity on $B$.

Comment: Is there an 'easy' characterisation of functions when the property holds? For example, the class of any constant function $f(x)=c$ will have $f$ as a canonical representant, in the sense above.

Comment: I think it's only functions whose essential range is discrete; whenever there's a limit point of the essential range, you should be able to make a similar argument.